# What versions of pharo, etc. should I use for new development?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am preparing to do some open-source development that I have been thinking about for some time.  It will ultimately be a cloud-based web service that interrogates other web services.  As one of the joys of this work, I can call the shots and return to my 90s-era Smalltalk roots.  I've settled on Pharo and (at least initially) Seaside.  But it has been almost 15 years since my last real Smalltalk work.  So I am unfamiliar with the current ecosystem.  Which versions of Pharo and Seaside are stable enough for real work?  And where and what else do you suggest a returning Smalltalker explore before beginning?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well, the stable version is Pharo 2.0 and Seaside 3.0.9.

(Both pharo 3 and seaside 3.1 are already a lot better, but since they are development versions, I wouldn't recommend them for production yet).

Comment: Stable Pharo version as of August 2014 is Pharo 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need Zinc to interrogate web services: https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/PharoForTheEnterprise/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/Zinc/Zinc.pier.html

I can only encourage you to join the Pharo users mailing list and IRC channel.

You may also want to have a look at the books: http://www.pharo-project.org/documentation/tutorials-books